# bash error "command not found" when using if with "or" operator

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

So I am trying out this if elif code in UNIX using "bash script" and it is giving me this Output

```
script[11]: pc4: command not found
script[14]: pc4: command not found
```

instead of "-o" I previously had "|" as the "or" Operator but that wasn't working. Also, I had brackets before but yeah...

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
test1="pc4"
test2="pc5"
prod1="t01"
prod2="t02"
prod3="t03"
prod4="t04"
path="/home/test1/test2/test3"

if "$host" = "$test1" -o "$host" = "$test2"
   then
       echo "test loaded"
elif "$host" = "$prod1" -o "$host" = "$prod2" -o "$host" = "$prod3" -o "$host" = "$prod4"
   then
       echo "prod loaded"
else
       echo "bad host"
fi
```

edit: fixed it, it had to be:

```
if [ "$host" = "$test1" -o "$host" = "$test2" ];
...
...
elif [ "$host" = "$prod1" -o "$host" = "$prod2" -o "$host" = "$prod3" -o "$host" = "$prod4" ];
```

thanks to all!

Comment: `|` is piping, `||` would be or. But `if` works based on the return value of a command, so you want to wrap the condition in `[ ... ]`. Note that `[` is itself a command, and not part of any syntax.

Comment: @Siguza okay tried again with adding [], now it works, maybe I forgot using spaces after and before brackets. thanks, is || = or for only bash or also in General the or? thought it was |

Comment: In most programming languages, `|` is bitwise or while `||` is logical or.

Comment: If your issue was resolved, you should [accept the appropriate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling a commmand; `-o` is an operator of the `test` command, although its use is not recommended.

```
if test "$host" = "$test1" -o "$host" = "$test2"
then
   echo "test loaded"
elif test "$host" = "$prod1" -o "$host" = "$prod2" -o "$host" = "$prod3" -o "$host" = "$prod4"
then
   echo "prod loaded"
else
   echo "bad host"
fi
```

Instead, use multiple calls to `test` joined by the *shell* operator `||`. (Line breaks may be easily added after `||` for readability.)

```
if test "$host" = "$test1" || 
   test "$host" = "$test2"
then
    echo "test loaded"
elif test "$host" = "$prod1" ||
     test "$host" = "$prod2" ||
     test "$host" = "$prod3" || 
     test "$host" = "$prod4"
then
    echo "prod loaded"
else
    echo "bad host"
fi
```

Finally, you may want to consider using a `case` statement instead:

```
case $host of
    "$test1"|"$test2" ) echo "test loaded" ;;
    "$prod1"|"$prod2"|"$prod3"|"$prod4") echo "prod loaded" ;;
    *) echo "bad host" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
test1="pc4"
test2="pc5"
prod1="t01"
prod2="t02"
prod3="t03"
prod4="t04"
path="/home/test1/test2/test3"

if [[ "$host" == "$test1" ]] || [[ "$host" == "$test2" ]]
then
  echo "test loaded"
elif [[ "$host" == "$prod1" ]] || [[ "$host" == "$prod2" ]] || [[ "$host" == "$prod3" ]] || [[ "$host" == "$prod4" ]]
then
  echo "prod loaded"
else
  echo "bad host"
fi
```

Though it is true that only an "=" is needed for string equality comparison, the "=" is also used as the assignment operator. Hence, so as to reduce possible confusion and as a 'best practice', I would use "==" for string equality . It so happens that "==" is just a synonym for "=" but I prefer not to use the same operator for multiple purposes.
NOTE:  I am not implying POSIX compatibilty.

Comment: If you're going to suggest `==` over `=`, use `[[ ]]` as well -- that way you aren't implying compatibility with POSIX test, for which the standard explicitly only defines `=` as supported.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Good point, I'll add that to my response.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `if` and `elif` conditions in brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
test1="pc4"
test2="pc5"
prod1="t01"
prod2="t02"
prod3="t03"
prod4="t04"
path="/home/test1/test2/test3"

if [ "$host" = "$test1" -o "$host" = "$test2" ]
   then
       echo "test loaded"
elif [ "$host" = "$prod1" -o "$host" = "$prod2" -o "$host" = "$prod3" -o "$host" = "$prod4" ]
   then
       echo "prod loaded"
else
       echo "bad host"
fi
```

Please note that the space before and after `[` is crucial.

Comment: "Brackets" are not shell syntax: `[` is a **command**, which can be implemented as a shell builtin or found in `/usr/bin/[` (or `/bin/[`, depending on your operating system) -- and which is often implemented by the same command as the `test` command (either by being a second entry for the same builtin function, or a hardlink to the same on-disk file). Moreover, `-o` is explicitly marked obsolescent by the current version of the POSIX test standard; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html (and the various `[OB]` markers).

Answer (score 0):

`-o` is a syntax supported by `test` command or `[` command.

So enclose your condition withing `[` and `]` as shown:

```
if [ "$host" = "$test1" -o "$host" = "$test2" ];
then
       echo "test loaded"
elif [ "$host" = "$prod1" -o "$host" = "$prod2" -o "$host" = "$prod3" -o "$host" = "$prod4" ];
then
       echo "prod loaded"
else
       echo "bad host"
fi
```

Refer this [link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Comment: Note that the modern POSIX `test` standard marks `-o` and `-a` as obsolescent, and invocations of `test` with more than four arguments as having results undefined by the standard. See the `[OB]` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
test1="pc4"
test2="pc5"
prod1="t01"
prod2="t02"
prod3="t03"
prod4="t04"
path="/home/test1/test2/test3"

if [ "$host" = "$test1" ] || [ "$host" = "$test2" ] ; then
echo "test loaded"
elif [ "$host" = "$prod1" ] || [ "$host" = "$prod2" ] || [ "$host" = "$prod3" ] || [ "$host" = "$prod4" ] 
   then
       echo "prod loaded"
else
       echo "bad host"
fi
```